# Failed to create AV capture input device: Cannot use Built-in Microphone

Tags: ffmpeg, microphone

I want to record the microphone on macOS with FFMPEG. I run:

```bsh
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":1" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ac 1 output.mp3
```

and get this error:

```
[avfoundation @ 0x7fcf2b000800] Failed to create AV capture input device: Cannot use Built-in Microphone
```

The output before the error message is:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

How can I record microphone sound with FFMPEG on macOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminal needs access to your microphone. Go to `System Preferences` (Apple sign on top left corner, then menu item `System Preferences...`), click on the `Security & Privacy` item, then on the `Privacy` tab. If the Terminal app is listed and is unchecked, click the checkbox, then restart Terminal.app.

Comment: It's checked, but it still fails if it's run in a Launch Daemon... how do I add access to the Launch Daemon - the Privacy tabs doesn't let me add anything.

Comment: @Michael I never had that problem and have no experience with daemons. I suggest asking a separate question and cross-linking the threads.